# converting TSQL with count on join to LINQ

Tags: linq, asp.net-web-api, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have worked out the Azure SQL statement I need, now I would like to convert it to Linq code.  I am working with .Net 6.  Concept is simple, there are customers and those customers can have rules, don't need to.  Some have the feature turned off altogether (customer.AutoAssignPaRequests) other customers can have set to true (1) but not have any active rules in the rules table.

The query returns all the customers that have the feature enabled and has rules:

```
SELECT c.CustomerId
     , c.AutoAssignPaRequests
     , COUNT(aar.AutoAssignmentRuleId) AS RuleCount
  FROM Customers                         c
           LEFT JOIN AutoAssignmentRules aar ON aar.CustomerId = c.CustomerId AND aar.IsActive = 1
 WHERE c.AutoAssignPaRequests = 1
 GROUP BY c.CustomerId, c.AutoAssignPaRequests
HAVING COUNT(aar.AutoAssignmentRuleId) > 0
 ORDER c.CustomerId;
```

I tried to convert it to Linq and it worked fine in LinqPAD 7:

```
  var customerQuery = 
     from c in context.Customers.AsNoTracking()
     where c.AutoAssignPaRequests == true
     join aar in context.AutoAssignmentRules on 
        new { c.CustomerId, IsActive = true } equals new{ aar.CustomerId, aar.IsActive } into rulesGroup
     where rulesGroup.Any()
     select c.CustomerId;

  var customerList = await customerQuery.ToListAsync();
```

But when it is put in to the ASP.Net 6 app, it generates this error:

```
      System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Customer>()
          .Where(c => c.AutoAssignPaRequests == True)
          .GroupJoin(
              inner: DbSet<AutoAssignmentRule>(),
              outerKeySelector: c => new {
                  CustomerId = c.CustomerId,
                  IsActive = True
               },
              innerKeySelector: aar => new {
                  CustomerId = aar.CustomerId,
                  IsActive = aar.IsActive
               },
              resultSelector: (c, rulesGroup) => new {
                  c = c,
                  rulesGroup = rulesGroup
               })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
```

Comment: LINQ doesn't query databases, ORMs like EF and NHibernate do. They don't deal with tables either. You may not need any JOINs your entities have the proper relations. You could write eg `context.Customers.Where(c=>c.Rules.Count()>0 && c.AutoAssignPaRequests).Select(c=>new {c.CustomerId, RuleCount=c.Rules.Count());`. What do your *entities* and DbContext model look like?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the model was poorly designed, the customer does not have a collection of AutoAssignmentRules and the AutoAssignmentRules only has the customerId, not a reference to the object.

Comment: In that case it should be fixed, not covered up. I can't repeat enough that EF *doesn't* deal with tables, it deals with entities. It's not just querying, it's *persistence* as well. When you attach a new object, all the related objects are attached as well, in the correct state. Adding or removing related items ensures the correct changes are made. When you call `SaveChanges` all the pending changes are saved in the correct order

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree, you cannot repeat enough that EF doesn't deal with tables.  I say that because in all the years I have worked with EF, this is the first I have heard that and ... it makes total sense!  You have totally shifted the way I look at EF now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not need LEFT JOIN and filter by HAVING. I have rewritten your query and it should return the same result:

```cs
var customerQuery = 
   from c in context.Customers
   where c.AutoAssignPaRequests == true
   from aar in context.AutoAssignmentRules.Where(aar => c.CustomerId == aar.CustomerId && aar.IsActive)
   group c by new { c.CustomerId, c.AutoAssignPaRequests } into g
   select new 
   {
      g.Key.CustomerId,
      g.Key.AutoAssignPaRequests,
      RuleCount = g.Count()
   } into s
   orderby s.CustomerId
   select s;

var customerList = await customerQuery.ToListAsync();
```